# Atomic function pointer call compiles in gcc, but not in clang and msvc

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, atomic, stdatomic

When calling function from an atomic function pointer, like:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <type_traits>

int func0(){ return 0; }

using func_type = std::add_pointer<int()>::type;

std::atomic<func_type> f = { func0 };

int main(){
        f();
}
```

gcc doesn't complain at all, while clang and msvc have problem with call `f()`:

- [clang]: error: call to object of type 'std::atomic<func_type>' (aka 'atomic<int (*)()>') is ambiguous
- [msvc]: there is more than one way an object of type "std::atomic<func_type>" can be called for the argument list

Clang additionally specifies possible call candidates to be:

- `operator __pointer_type() const noexcept`
- `operator __pointer_type() const volatile noexcept`

It seems like this difference in volatility is confusing for clang and msvc, but not gcc.

When call is changed from `f()` to `f.load()()`, the code works in all abovementioned compilers. Which is all the more confusing, since both [`load()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load) and [`operator T()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T) are said to have `const` and `const volatile` overloads - if implicit conversion doesn't work, I'd expect `load()` not to work as well. Are the rules somehow different within implicit conversions (versus member calls)?

So, is gcc wrong to accept that code? Are clang and msvc wrong to error out? Any other combination of being wrong or right?

---

This is mostly a theoretical question, but if there is some better way to have an atomic function pointer, I'd like to know.

Comment: All the compilers like `(*f)();` but I am not sure what the difference is - I guess it's the same as `f.load()()` (as above).

Comment: @RichardCritten That's interesting, though I think `(*f)()` is more like `f()`, because `operator T()` is used implicitly for both (whereas there's no conversion in `f.load()()`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Clang and MSVC are correct.

For each conversion function to a function pointer of the class, a so-called *surrogate call function* is added to overload resolution, which if chosen would first convert the object via this operator overload to a function pointer and then call the function via the function pointer. This is explained in [[over.call.object]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.call.object#2).

However, the surrogate call function does not translate the cv-qualifiers of the conversion operator in any way. So, since `std::atomic` has a conversion operator which is `volatile` and one which is not, there will be two indistinguishable surrogate call functions. These are also the only candidates since `std::atomic` doesn't have any actual `operator()` and so overload resolution must always be ambiguous.

There is even a footnote in the standard mentioning that this can happen, see [[over.call.object]/footnote.120](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.call.object#footnote-120).

With a direct call to `.load()` the `volatile`-qualifier will be a tie-breaker in overload resolution, so this issue doesn't appear.

With `(*f)()` overload resolution on the (built-in) `operator*` with the function pointer type as parameter is performed. There are two implicit conversion sequences via the two conversion functions. The standard isn't very clear on it, but I think the intention is that this doesn't result in an ambiguous conversion sequence (which would also imply ambiguous overload resolution when it is chosen). Instead I think it is intended that the rules for initialization by conversion function are applied to select only one of the conversions, which would make it unambiguously the `volatile`-qualified one.

Comment: @ixSci If the object is `volatile`-qualified, then overload resolution shouldn't be ambiguous. The surrogate call function is generated only for conversion functions which are at least as cv-qualified as the object is. (See linked standard reference.) So MSVC is wrong then.

Comment: You are right, filed [a bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Incorrect-overload-resolution-for-cv-qui/10027294?port=1026&fsid=be769c70-bdde-4b10-ba61-b2c1cd4358bb&entry=problem).

Comment: Huh, that is interesting. But it begs the question: why doesn't standard say that this surrogate call function have the same cv-qualification as the conversion operator it's based on? Are there any problems with that?

Comment: @ja2142 In "normal" overload resolution on a member function call the cv-qualifier of the function works by accordingly qualifying the implicit object parameter of the function. The conversion of the object expression to the implicit object parameter then has the mentioned tie-breaker applied.

Comment: In the case of the surrogate call function, the first parameter of the function submitted for overload resolution is not the implicit object parameter, but instead a parameter of the target function pointer type. This type already has its own cv-qualifications. So there is no place to sensibly add the cv-qualifiers of the conversion function. I am not sure there is any simple solution to this issue. Maybe some additional explicit tie-breakers for surrogate call functions, or `std::atomic` could add proper `operator()` overloads.

Comment: @user17732522 So, surrogate call function is not a member?

Comment: @ja2142 For overload resolution member functions are considered the same as non-member functions, except that an additional first parameter is added to them, called the _implicit object parameter_, which is a reference to the class type qualified according to the cv-qualifiers and ref-qualifiers of the member function. Since the surrogate call function "exists" only for the purpose of overload resolution, it isn't really useful to ask whether it is a member. It is not a member at least in the sense that the aforementioned transformation is not applied.

Comment: OK, I'm stupid.  #1) where does `volatile` enter into it at all?  (There's no such keyword in the example and I don't see any in `std::atomic` over there at cppreference either.)  #2) Doesn't this mean you can't use the `f()` syntax to call _any_ 0-arg function through an atomic pointer?

Comment: @davidbak I don't fully grasp that myself, but: #1) there are two overloads of conversion from `atomic<T>` to `T` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T) - one `const volatile`, one `const`. `f` not being volatile, is actually part of a problem here - if I understand this correctly, if `f` is volatile, only `volatile` conversion operator would be considered, and only one surrogate call function would be generated - there's no ambiguity. #2) I think it means you can't use `f()` to call any function through atomic pointer that isn't volatile (you can do `(*f)()`, etc.).

Comment: @davidbak `std::atomic` has it's member functions duplicated, once with a `volatile`-qualifier and once without, so that `volatile std::atomic` variables can be used, but at the same time optimizations on non-volatile variables can be performed (see [LWG 1147](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1147)). `std::atomic` doesn't have a `operator()` overload at all, so it would seem that any call `f(...)` (no matter the number of arguments) shouldn't work at all. You would need to always load the function pointer from the `std::atomic` explicitly with `.load()` before calling it.

Comment: But there is a somewhat obscure rule in the standard that says that if the class has a conversion operator to a function pointer, then overload resolution may choose to first convert via this conversion operator and then call the resulting function pointer. That's the surrogate call function discussed above. However this rule does not work if there are multiple conversion operators which differ only in `const`/`volatile`-qualification as is the case for `std::atomic`. So, as long as `f` is not `volatile`-qualified, `f(...)` still does never work, no matter how many arguments are used.

Comment: I can't tell you whether this is an oversight in the design of `std::atomic` or whether it was not deemed important enough use case to add a proper `operator()` overload that would make it work. In any case, `f.load()(...)` with `...` replaced by as many arguments as necessary to call the stored function will always work fine.